# ImportError: cannot import name 'load_mnist' from 'pytorchcv'

Tags: computer-vision, pytorch

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-2cacdf187bba> in <module>
      6 import numpy as np
      7 
----> 8 from pytorchcv import load_mnist, train, plot_results, plot_convolution, display_dataset
      9 load_mnist(batch_size=128)

ImportError: cannot import name 'load_mnist' from 'pytorchcv' (/anaconda/envs/py37_pytorch/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pytorchcv/__init__.py)
```

How can fix this bug? 
I use python 3.7 and Jupiter notebook. The code in Pytorch Fundamental of Microsoft: Link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/learn/modules/intro-computer-vision-pytorch/5-convolutional-networks

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torchvision
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from torchinfo import summary
import numpy as np

from pytorchcv import load_mnist, train, plot_results, plot_convolution, display_dataset
load_mnist(batch_size=128)
```

I installed PyTorch by `pip install pytorchcv`.

Comment: Mnist is not a model... are you trying to load the actual dataset?

Comment: I want to load a dataset and the code was written by a Microsoft developer in Pytorch Fundamental Course.  I have mentioned the link above. @Ivan

Comment: As the Problem appeared in the ''import from pytorchcv import load_mnist'', one can assume that the version of pytorchcv you installed does not contain the method load mnist. Could you provide the output for the pytorchcv.__version__ ?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you might have the wrong pytorchcv package. The one in pypy does not contain `load_mnist`

Starting from scratch you could download mnist as such:

```
data_train = torchvision.datasets.MNIST('./data',
        download=True,train=True,transform=ToTensor()) data_test = torchvision.datasets.MNIST('./data',
        download=True,train=False,transform=ToTensor())
```

Answer (score 1):

They missed one command before importing pytorchcv.
This pytorchcv is different from pytorchcv in PyPI.

Run this before importing pytorchcv.

```
!wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/MicrosoftDocs/pytorchfundamentals/main/computer-vision-pytorch/pytorchcv.py
```

Then it should work.

Answer (score 0):

please download the prepared py file from the link https://raw.githubusercontent.com/MicrosoftDocs/pytorchfundamentals/main/computer-vision-pytorch/pytorchcv.py and put it into current folder, then VS Code could recognize it